# Compound assignment operators, what happens if the value is modified (in the meanwhile)?

Tags: language-agnostic, programming-languages, operators, pseudocode, compound-assignment

Consider the following pseudocode (language agnostic):

```
int f(reference int y) {
   y++;

   return 2;
}

int v = 1;

v += f(v);
```

When the function `f` changes `y` (that is `v`) while evaluating `v += f(v)`, is the original value of `v` "frozen" and changes to `v` "lost"?

```
v += f(v); // Compute the address of v (l-value)
           // Evaluate v (1)
           // Execute f(v), which returns 2
           // Store 1 + 2 
printf(v); // 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most languages `+=` operator (as well as any other compound assignment operator, as well as simple assignment operator) has right-to-left associativity. That means `f(v)` value will be evaluated first, *then* its result will be added to the *current* value of `v`.

So in your example it should be 4, not 3:

**C++:** ([demo](http://codepad.org/NXUYIP1Y))

```
int f(int& v) {
  v++;
  return 2;
}

int main() {
  int v = 1;
  v += f(v);
  cout << v; // 4
}
```

**Perl:** ([demo](http://codepad.org/hCoV0y6g))

```
sub f {
  $_[0]++;
  return 2;
}

my $v = 1;
$v += f($v);

print $v; # 4
```

Comment: That is, the same as _just increment the value of v by the quantity on the right side_, right?

Comment: I'd say 'evaluate the right side, then increment v by its result'. The key point here is the order of evaluation.

Comment: Good, got the point. Thanks for your answer and live examples.